# Python Syntax Issues

Tags: python

What's wrong with the following code, it keeps giving an error "Not all arguments converted during string formatting":

```
mealPrice = raw_input ("How much did you pay for your meal?: ")

hst1 = 0.13
hst1 = int(hst1)
totalprice = (float(mealPrice) * hst1)

print "Cost of meal", mealPrice
print "Taxes", hst
print "-------------------------------"
print "Total", totalPrice
```

Answer (score 4):

First, all you need to do to specify the tax rate is this:

```
hst1 = 0.13
```

It looks like you're trying to make a string out of that number, and then turn it into an integer. Don't do that; just make a floating-point value and use it.

Second, raw_input will return a string value. You will want to convert that to a number before you use it:

```
mealPrice = float(mealPrice)
```

After that, your indentation looks way off -- perhaps that's just because of the way you pasted your code in, but all of your lines should start at the same column.

Finally, the last line reads 'end' -- this is not python syntax, and shouldn't be there. Delete that.

Comment: and also `(float(mealPrice) * hst1)`.

Comment: is this good? 'mealPrice = raw_input ("How much did you pay for your meal?: ")

    hst1 = 0.13
    hst1 = int(hst1)
    totalprice = (float(mealPrice) * hst1)

    print "Cost of meal", mealPrice
    print "Taxes", hst
    print "-------------------------------"
    print "Total", totalPrice'

Comment: If you use `hst1 = int(hst1)`, then hst1 will become 0. `int` turns things into integers -- i.e., 0, 1, 2, 3 -- so 0.13 becomes 0. I'd take that line out.